# jQuery sort by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="col col1">
   <div class="colSub1"></div>
   <div class="colSub1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col col2">
   <div class="colSub2"></div>
   <div class="colSub2"></div>
   <div class="colSub2"></div>
</div>
<div class="col col3">
   <div class="colSub3"></div>
   <div class="colSub3"></div>
</div>
```

I want to sort this like this, without the parent div:

```
<div class="colSub1"></div>
<div class="colSub2"></div>
<div class="colSub3"></div>
<div class="colSub1"></div>
<div class="colSub2"></div>
<div class="colSub3"></div>
<div class="colSub2"></div>
```

What is the most effective and fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps:

1. Find the element with the largest number of "children".
2. Loop over the max number and in the columns so in each iteration it will take from the `.col` one item.

If something not clear, please let me know.

**The working code:**

```js
var cols = $('.col');
var max = Math.max.apply(null, cols.map(function() {
  return $(this).children().length;
}).get());

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
    $('#result').append(cols.eq(j).children().eq(i).clone());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Before</h3>
<div class="col col1">
  <div class="colSub1">col1 - colSub1</div>
  <div class="colSub1">col1 - colSub1</div>
</div>
<div class="col col2">
  <div class="colSub2">col2 - colSub2</div>
  <div class="colSub2">col2 - colSub2</div>
  <div class="colSub2">col2 - colSub2</div>
</div>
<div class="col col3">
  <div class="colSub3">col3 - colSub3</div>
  <div class="colSub3">col3 - colSub3</div>
</div>

<hr />
<h3>After</h3>
<div id="result"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/lavemu/edit?html,js